# fit a curve with model equation numpy

Tags: numpy, least-squares

I am trying to reproduce a curve with a model equation using non-linearleast square procedure to get out a certain "beta" value. The y and x experimental data are two 1D numpy arrays of the same size, namely "a" and "angle_plot" respectively. The code I am using produce an error: " 'float' object is not callable ". What is wrong with my code? Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

a = array([ 0.04022493,  0.04287536,  0.03983657,  0.0393201 ,  0.03810298,
    0.0363814 ,  0.0331144 ,  0.03074823,  0.02795767,  0.02413816,
    0.02180802,  0.01861309,  0.01632699,  0.01368056,  0.01124232,
    0.01005323,  0.00867196,  0.00940864,  0.00961282,  0.00892419,
    0.01048963,  0.01199101,  0.01533408,  0.01855704,  0.02163586,
    0.02630014,  0.02971127,  0.03511223,  0.03941218,  0.04280329,
    0.04689105,  0.04960554,  0.05232003,  0.05487037,  0.05843364,
    0.05120701])

angle_plot = array([ 0.        ,  0.08975979,  0.17951958,  0.26927937,  0.35903916,
    0.44879895,  0.53855874,  0.62831853,  0.71807832,  0.80783811,
    0.8975979 ,  0.98735769,  1.07711748,  1.16687727,  1.25663706,
    1.34639685,  1.43615664,  1.52591643,  1.61567622,  1.70543601,
    1.7951958 ,  1.88495559,  1.97471538,  2.06447517,  2.15423496,
    2.24399475,  2.33375454,  2.42351433,  2.51327412,  2.60303391,
    2.6927937 ,  2.78255349,  2.87231328,  2.96207307,  3.05183286,
    3.14159265])



def residual(vars, x, data):
   beta = vars[0]
   model = 1/(4*np.pi)(1+beta*(3/2*np.cos(x)**2-1/2)) 
   return data-model

vars = [0.2]
out = leastsq(residual, vars, args=(angle_plot, a))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a multiplication operator (I presume) between `(4*np.pi)` and `(1+beta*(3/2*np.cos(x)**2-1/2))`.

It should be:

```
def residual(vars, x, data):
   beta = vars[0]
   model = 1/(4*np.pi)*(1+beta*(3/2*np.cos(x)**2-1/2)) 
   return data-model
```

Without the `*` you're effectively trying to call `1/(4*np.pi)` as a function such as `np.cos`.

Comment: That's true. I could not see it. Now seems to work but I would like to plot experimental vs model to see the goodness of the fit. Where can I get the fitting from? thanks

Comment: That is a **completely** different question, which you should ask separately.